# Yii2 autocomplete no response

Tags: autocomplete, yii2

Am trying to display users list as mail.Here it is my code,but there is no response

```
<?php
 $data = Users::find()
    ->select(['user_email as value', 'user_id as id'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

  echo AutoComplete::widget([
    'name' => 'user_email',
    'id' => 'ddd',
    'clientOptions' => [
    'source' => $data,
    'autoFill'=>true,
    'minLength'=>'1',
    'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
        $('#user_mail_1').val(ui.item.id);

     }")],
     ]);
            ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'user_email')->HiddenInput(['id' => 'user_mail_1'])->label(false) ?>
```

Comment: check browser console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `label` for display value of auto complete input value.

So, get `user_email` as `label` like as:

```
<?php
 use yii\web\JsExpression;


 $data = Users::find()
         ->select(['user_email as value', 'user_id as id', 'user_email as label'])
         ->asArray()
        ->all();

 // OR try below query for get data.

 $data = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(["user_email as value", "user_email as label","user_id as id"])
        ->from('users u')
        ->all();


  echo AutoComplete::widget([
    'name' => 'user_email',
    'id' => 'ddd',
    'clientOptions' => [
    'source' => $data,
    'autoFill'=>true,
    'minLength'=>'1',
    'select' => new JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
        $('#".Html::getInputId($model, 'user_email')."').val(ui.item.id); // Html::gtInputId() get dynamic id of input field.

     }")],
     ]);
            ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'user_email')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
```

Comment: what's happens. can you post span of this.?

Comment: I have edited my ans. and i have added `Query` for getting data from DB. so check it out.